# QQ-plot python mean and standard deviation

Tags: python, plot, normal-distribution

I am trying to plot a Q-Q plot using python. I was checking scipy.stats.probplot, and the input seems to be the measurement against a normal distributiom.

```
import numpy as np 
import pylab 
import scipy.stats as stats

measurements = np.random.normal(loc = 20, scale = 5, size=100)   
stats.probplot(measurements, dist="norm", plot=pylab)
pylab.show()
```

and in my code, I had

```
stats.probplot(mean, dist="norm", plot=plt)
```

to compare distributions.

But I am wondering where can I input standard deviation? I thought that's a very important factor when comparing distributions but so far I can only input the mean.

Thanks

Comment: What is `mean`? Can you include it in the post?

Comment: mean is the average line of my data observations (from gaussian process)

Comment: I mean can you include your sample data in your post so that people can copy pate it and try to find a working solution

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a list on float

```
X = [-1.31,
 4.82,
 2.18,
 1.99,
 4.37,
 2.58,
 7.22,
 3.93,
 6.95,
 2.41,
 2.02,
 2.48,
 -1.01,
 2.3,
 2.87,
 -0.06,
 2.13,
 3.62,
 5.24,
 0.57]
```

If you want to make a QQ_plot test you need to compare X against a distribution.
For example : N(0, 1) a normal distribution whose mean = 0 and sigma = 1

In OpenTURNS, it goes like that:

```
import openturns as ot

sample = ot.Sample([[p] for p in X])  
graph = ot.VisualTest.DrawQQplot(sample, ot.Normal(0,1))
View(graph);
```

Explanation:  I tell OpenTURNS I have a sample of 20 points [p] coming from X and not 1 point in dimension 20. Then I call `ot.VisualTest.DrawQQplot` with 2 arguments: `sample` and the Normal distribution (0,1) `ot.Normal(0,1)`.

We see on the graph that the test fails:

[image]

The question now is: what is the best Normal Distribution fitting the sample?
Thanks to `NormalFactory()` the answer is simple:

```
BestNormalDistribution = ot.NormalFactory().build(sample)
```

If you `print(BestNormalDistribution)` you get the parameters of this distribution:
Normal(mu = 2.76832, sigma = 2.27773)

If we repeat the QQ_plot test of `sample` against `BestNormalDistribution` it would be much better
[image]